# How to create an object by class and get information from the list in Python?

Tags: python, list, class, elementtree

I'm working in Python with class and ElementTree

I have a function to get the news from Yahoo XML include title, date of public, and the link then I stored them into a list:

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def get_contents():
    url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss'

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        data = response.read()
        root = ET.fromstring(data)
        channel = root[0]
        titles = [nt.text for nt in channel.iter('title')]
        dates = [pd.text for pd in channel.iter('pubDate')]
        links = [nl.text for nl in channel.iter('link')]
        contents = [[titles[i], dates[i], links[i]] for i in range(len(titles) - 1)]

    return contents
```

I also have a class Content that include the **init** function to declare the title, date of public, and the link. Also, I have the **str** function to get the format string of an object if I create them:

```
class Content():
    def __init__(self, title, link, pub_date):
        # TODO: your code here
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self.pub_date = pub_date
    def __str__(self):
        # TODO: your code here
        return self.title + '. (' + self.pub_date + ')' + '\n' + self.link
```

Now, I want to create an object by the class Content() and get the title, public date, and link by the list I have (in the get_contents() function return) like:

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a list of values, you can just create the Content item directly, then you can print it out:

```python
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

class Content():
    def __init__(self, title, link, pub_date):
        self.title = title
        self.link = link
        self.pub_date = pub_date
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + '. (' + self.pub_date + ')' + '\n' + self.link

def get_contents():
    url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss'

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
        data = response.read()
        root = ET.fromstring(data)
        for item in root.findall("./channel/item"):
            title = item.findtext("title")
            pubDate = item.findtext("pubDate")
            link = item.findtext("link")
            yield Content(title, link, pubDate)


for content in get_contents():
    print(content)
```

Also, you can save yourself a bit of work by using a third party library like `feedparser` to parse the RSS feed:

```python
import feedparser
def get_contents():
    url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/news/rss'
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)
    for item in feed.entries:
        yield Content(item.title, item.link, item.published)
```